# AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderException: User is not authorized to perform cognito-idp:DescribeUserPool on resource

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I am learning integrating AWS with an ASP .NET Core site. I am using AWS Cognito as a user store. I have created a sign-up form which actually acts as an interface to AWS Cognito. So far I have done the following steps:

1. Created an User Pool in AWS Cognito.
2. Created an User in IAM service. Attached the existing policy   "AmazonCognitoDeveloperAuthenticatedIdentities" to this User.
3. Created a credentials file in Windows in the user profile directory. Set the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key in this file
4. In the appsettings.json file created an AWS section and set keys as below (I have hidden the User Pool Client Secret):

   ```
   "AWS": {

   "Region": "us-east-2",

   "UserPoolClientId": "44m80ksabq0knieeg81ina2npj",

   "UserPoolClientSecret": XXXXXX,

   "UserPoolId": "us-east-2_115WHTcaH"
    }
   ```
5. I have imported the Amazon.AspNetCore.Identity.Cognito and Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication nuget packages. Using these packages, I have passed CognitoUser as the T parameter to the SignInManager and UserManager of ASP .NET Core Identity classes. Below is the entire code of the controller.

   ```
   public class Accounts : Controller
   {
       SignInManager<CognitoUser> _signInManager;
       UserManager<CognitoUser> _userManager;
       CognitoUserPool _pool;

       public Accounts(SignInManager<CognitoUser> signInManager, UserManager<CognitoUser> 
         userManager, CognitoUserPool pool)
       {
           _signInManager = signInManager;
           _userManager = userManager;
           _pool = pool;
       }


       [HttpPost]
       public async Task<IActionResult> SignUp(SignupModel model)
       {
           if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
               var user = _pool.GetUser(model.Email);
               if (user.Status != null)
               {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("UserExists", "User with this email already exists");
                   return View(model);
               }

               user.Attributes.Add(CognitoAttribute.Name.AttributeName, model.Email);
               var createdUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
               if (createdUser.Succeeded)
               {
                   RedirectToAction("Confirm");
               }
           }
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```

When I execute this code, I get an error when trying to create an user (await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)) as

```
AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderException: User: arn:aws:iam::777844316068:user/xxxx is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:DescribeUserPool on resource: arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:777844316068:userpool/us-east-2_115WHTcaH
```

I know this has to do with the Policy at IAM but I am not able to figure out the exact setting I am missing. Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user is not an administrator add to IAM uesrs permissions AdministratorAccess

Answer (score 0):

Go to IAM users, select user, click "add inline policy", find a service "Cognito User Pools", search the action "DescribeUserPool", add user pool arn, create a policy